# How to fix this java.util.Scanner.next, throwing java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, jcombobox

I am filtering new lines but first time it worked on second loop its failing for `line 2` filering.

Exception:

```
run:
a[line 1]l[0]
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
a[line 2]l[1]
a[line 3]l[2]
b[line 1]l[0]
b[line 3]l[1]
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:855)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1364)
    at ui.Test.main(Test.java:82)
```

Code:

```
// a) Lines
String a = "line 1\n\r" +
           "line 2\n\r" +
           "line 3\n\r";                
// b) Total length 
int len = 0;    
Scanner sc = new Scanner(a).useDelimiter("\r?\n\r|\\|");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println("a[" + sc.next() + "]l[" +  len + "]" ); 
  len++;
}

// c) Prepare array 
String[] value;
value = new String[len+1];
len = 0;    
sc = new Scanner(a).useDelimiter("\r?\n\r|\\|");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println("b[" + sc.next() + "]l[" +  len + "]" ); 
  value[len] = sc.next();
  len++;
}

// d) Goal - use the value for JComboBox
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: FYI, `System.out.println(value)` won't work the way you think.  If you want to print arrays, use `Arrays.toString` on them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling next twice in the second loop, call it once and store the value:

```
String val;
while (sc.hasNext()) {
  val=sc.next();
  System.out.println("b[" + val + "]l[" +  len + "]" ); 
  value[len] = val;
  len++;
}
```